# getting error while executing same query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-delete

This query working as expected in postgres but same query we need to write in Oracle could you please suggest how to write query in Oracle

```
delete from need_entl_status_history 
using  need_entitlement
where need_entitlement.need_entitlement_uuid=need_entl_status_history.need_entitlement_uuid
and need_entitlement.user_guid='b8e06968-2839-4fc1-a987-5ea81678d9ge’;
```

Comment: Open the documentation and see how you write delete statements? If you've tried, you should really include that too..

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like this; I used table aliases as they improve readability.

```
delete from need_entl_status_history h
  where h.need_entitlement_uuid in (select e.need_entitlement_uuid
                                    from need_entitlement e
                                    where e.user_guid = 'b8e06968-2839-4fc1-a987-5ea81678d9ge’
                                   );
```